# What happens if a solenoid has two counter-current coils around it?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

What happens if you wind two separate coils of a solenoid parallel to one another and connect them to two batteries such that current flows in opposite directions in the two coils?

$\hspace{150px}$[image]

Comment: You drain your batteries for no particularly good reason?

Comment: @Jon Custer Does it behave like lot of tiny magnets with attracting force between one another?

Comment: Are you thinking of a non-inductive wirewound resistor?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I did not know about this but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Done right, there is no net magnetic field since each coil cancels out the other. So, as @AlfredCentauri notes, it is a wirewound resistor with no induction (since there is no net magnetic field to store energy).

Comment: I assume current flow will be reduced due to the opposite induction. But seems tricky to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Both the coils will try to produce magnetic field in their own direction and as a result there will be joining and breaking of magnetic lines and heat will be produced.The total result of all this will be that the magnitude of the magnetic field will be less at the center and constant heat will be produced. It's the same kind of thing when earth's magnetic field interact's with sun's magnetic field.

For a cool video see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URN-XyZD2vQ).

Comment: That video is all about Earth's magnetic field interacting with the *solar wind*.  Of what relevance is that to this question?

Comment: Notice closely the change in the earth's magnetic field lines when it is constantly interacting (more like being bombarded) with the sun's magnetic field lines.The magnetic field of both the object's are dynamical and change continuously with time. This question will also follow the same trend when you look at it closely enough at the starting but at the end ,as people have mentioned, they will exactly cancel out if everything is perfect.